# Neo4j CSV import status updates

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I am trying to migrate from Mysql database to neo4j database. For the new neo4j database I planned the newsfeed feature as explained here http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html This mechanism is obviously different from mysql where the newsfeeds are just a bunch of rows. So is there a way to quickly import mysql rows into neo4j in `-[status_update]->()-[next]->()-` format? At the moment I have mysql database which looks like the following:

```
user table
+-------+--------------+
| id    | username     |
+-------+--------------+
| 1     | pewpewlasers |
+-------+--------------+

posts table
+-------+----------+------------+
| id    | user_id  | status     |
+-------+----------+------------+
| 1     | 1        | something  |
+-------+----------+------------+
| 2     | 1        | new update |
+-------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you output it as CSVs you could use `LOAD CSV` like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file/user.csv" AS line
CREATE (:User {id: toInt(line.id), username: line.username});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file/posts.csv" AS line
CREATE (:Post {id: toInt(line.id), line.status});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file/posts.csv" AS line
MATCH (user:User {id: toInt(line.user_id)})
MATCH (post:Post {id: toInt(line.id)})
CREATE user-[:status_update]->post;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/file/posts.csv" AS line
MATCH
  (post:Post {id: toInt(line.id)})
  (previous_post:Post {id: toInt(line.id) - 1})
CREATE previous_post-[:next]->post;
```

You might be able to combine some of those, but I'm always careful to split up queries because of the EAGER issue mentioned here:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Comment: Had to change few things, but this is the idea yes. Thanks!